# C++ auto detection of template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to define a recursive construct like a task farming. Here, I am trying for two operands which recursively can work for any number of operands as it can nest itself.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class Farm
{
  private:
    T1 *task1;
    T2 *task2;
  public:
    // save them so that I can use them when invoking call operator
    Farm(T1 *_t1, T2 *_t2): task1(_t1), task2(_t2) { }

    void operator()()
    {
      // invoke call operator, meaning a farm could be a task (arbitrary nesting)
      (*task1)();
      (*task2)();
    }
};
int main()
{
    ... create two pointer(A *a, B *b...)
    Farm(a,b); // error: missing template arguments before ‘(’ token

    Farm<A, B>(a,b); // in this works, it works
}
```

The problem is with auto-detection of template arguments which is not working in this case. What am I doing wrong and how could I achieve this template parameters implicit detection by gcc compiler.

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Before C++17, classes/constructors didn't autodetect types like functions do. You need to write a wrapper function to create your class.

This is done as follows and called the [Object Generator](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Object_Generator) pattern. (thanks @Itjax!)

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
Farm<T1, T2> makeFarm(T1* a, T2* b) {
      return Farm<T1,T2>(a,b);
}

// silly example
Farm<T1,T2> farm = makeFarm(a,b);

// better example
template<typename T>
void plow(T& farm) { farm.applyTractor(...); }

void blah() {
    plow(makeFarm(b,a)) 
}
```

This pattern emerges quite a lot when using lambda/bind/foreach and similar parts, when you want to create a temporary object of a templated class with some arguments and avoid specifying their type, usually sending it into another template function (`std::for_each`) or polymorphic object (`std::function`).

*Note:* The generator function usually inlines and with copy-elision optimization there will probably be no copy-constructor(s) called in your code at all. If you cannot copy your object, makeFarm() should return a smart pointer instead (`std::unique_ptr` is preferred in modern C++).

Comment: Exactly. This is called the Object Generator idiom: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Object_Generator

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But could you tell me how I can scale this _Farm_ to work for arbitrary template arguments (using C++0x variadic templates and possibly tuples). I have read alot and tries to do it but could not come up with a solution.

Comment: @user600029: That's a different question. Please search for that (or post a new question). Personally, I haven't used c++0x enough to help you with that, but I'm sure there are many others here that know how to do it properly.

Answer (score 4):

The usual workaround is to provide a template function which returns the real implementation. The standard C++ library uses this alot, e.g. with std::make_pair.

Example:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo_t {
    ...
};

template<typename T>
foo_t<T> foo(T const &f) {
    return foo_t<T>(f);
}
```

This works because for functions the compiler is allowed to deduce the typenames from the parameter list.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a base class for the class Farm:

```
class FarmBase
{
  public:
    virtual ~FarmBase(){}

    virtual void operator()() = 0;
};


template <typename T1, typename T2>
class Farm : public FramBase
{
  private:
    T1 *task1;
    T2 *task2;
  public:
    // save them so that I can use them when invoking call operator
    Farm(T1 *_t1, T2 *_t2): task1(_t1), task2(_t2) { }
    virtual ~Farm(){}

    virtual void operator()()
    {
      // invoke call operator, meaning a farm could be a task (arbitrary nesting)
      (*task1)();
      (*task2)();
    }
};
template< typename A, typename B >
FarmBase* Create( A *a, B *b )
{
  return new Farm< A, B >( a, b );
}
```

then the main looks like:

```
int main()
{
    //... create two pointer(A *a, B *b...)

    FarmBase *fobj = CreateFarm( a, b );
}
```

Comment: How would auto help in C++0x ? Just curious.